# Are there Synchronous Standard Step Functions Workflows

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronous, aws-step-functions

Are there Synchronous Standard Step Functions Workflows? Or Synchronous Workflows are only for express step-functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous is only available for Express Workflows. If you want to have your application start an Standard Workflows Execution and continue based on the result, you have three options:

1. If you are calling this from within another Standard Workflow, you can use the [.sync service integration pattern for Step Functions itself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html).
2. If you are building in an Event-Driven manner, you can use [Execution Status Change Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html).
3. You can add a loop to your code that calls StartExecution, gets the Execution ARN, then periodically calls to get the status, then returns the result. You could even implement that logic in an Express State machine, say building in the logic to break-out with a "still in progress" before the 5-minute timeout for express. Then call that as a Synchronous Express Execution.

Comment: So in the third part you are saying I can put a synchronous express step function Infront of a standard step functions and call it that way in a synchronous manner?